# (MySQL) Load data infile specific columns

Tags: mysql

I have a problem loading data into specific columns of an table.
The CSV file is build dynamic with the default fields ID, LAST_REFRESH, ALIAS1 and ***may contain*** ALIAS2 to ALIAS8. Current CSV only contains ALIAS1-4

The MySQL table contains the columns ID, LAST_REFRESH, ALIAS1-ALIAS8.
My code for the first file already fails. Code after variables are set is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\temp\\\OSS001'
INTO TABLE REJECTS (ID, REFRESH_DATE, ALIAS1, ALIAS2, ALIAS3, ALIAS4)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

But unfortunately i still receive the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
>       OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
>       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Anybody knows what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 16):

The column names have to be specified last. Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\temp\\\OSS001'
INTO TABLE REJECTS 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(ID, REFRESH_DATE, ALIAS1, ALIAS2, ALIAS3, ALIAS4, ALIAS5, ALIAS6, ALIAS7, ALIAS8)
```

Comment: I think you may have to catch this in your application logic. Not on database layer.

Comment: Already did it. I added a variable in the application that group_concats the alias fields :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the columns:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\temp\\\OSS001'
INTO TABLE REJECTS FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```