# I want to load specific column data from my CSV file(MySQL 8.0)

Tags: mysql, csv, loaddata

I created a discount Table which is like this

```
CREATE TABLE discounts (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
expired_date DATE NOT NULL,
amount DECIMAL(10 , 2 ) NULL,
created_at DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and I want to import specific column data(title,expired_date,amount) from my CSV. So I use this following SQL line.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/NewFolder/MYfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE discounts(title,expired_date,amount)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

But it gives me an error.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS' at line 3

MyFile.csv is like this

```
date         |title         |expired_date | amount | sales_person
2019/08/12   |ABC Company   |2019/08/12   |200     | John
2019/08/15   |Aroma Company |2019/08/16   |22      | Anna
2019/08/15   |Risona Company|2019/08/16   |268     | Anna
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!!

Sammy

Comment: If accurate, the sample from your CSV appears to have extra whitespace padding in many places.  Also note that the `title` column comes _second_, not first.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Hello, Paul
This is the Error 
12:55:22 LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/NewFolder/MYfile.csv'  INTO TABLE discounts(title,expired_date,amount) FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS' at line 3 0.000 sec

Comment: Did you try with ˋFIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'ˋ (and without ˋENCLOSED BY '"'ˋ)?

Comment: Yes!
But no luck

Comment: Any change in the error message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041188/mysql-load-data-infile-specific-columns look on this u need to decalre the columns in the last

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(MySQL) Load data infile specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041188/mysql-load-data-infile-specific-columns)

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data does not seem to match your import statement:

- The pipe character (not the comma) separates the fields, and
- there are no surrounding quotes.

You might want to try:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/NewFolder/MYfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE discounts(title,expired_date,amount)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, [the list of columns comes *last*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).

***UPDATE*** You also need to tell it to ignore the first row. You can do that with an unused variable. And your file is `|` delimited. And there are no quotes.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/NewFolder/MYfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE discounts
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 

LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@ignore,title,expired_date,amount);
```

Comment: I got Following Error
20:36:48 LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/NewFolder/MYfile.csv'  INTO TABLE discounts3 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS (title,expired_date,amount) Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: 'ABC Company' for column 'expired_date' at row 1 0.000 sec

Comment: @sami88rosh That's a different problem. Your database columns don't match your CSV columns. You have the second column as expired_date but it apparently contains a company name. You need a `@blank` first column.